# I switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu and now my internet is slow

Tags: networking

I am using a desktop computer with a wifi dongle. I used to use Arch Linux and this wasn't an issue, switched to Windows 10, and am now on Ubuntu. My wifi speed on Windows 10 was 100 mbps or higher. It is currently at 3 mbps. Already checked the driver (rt2800usb), disabled ipv6, tried liquorix kernel, and still nothing. As well as this, the dongle is not picking up some (but not all) 5GHz signals. I am not new to Linux, and have tried everything I can think of. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: I found that I need the rt2870 driver but cannot find the thing anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the adaptor just needs more Juice. As it is already a usb adaptor the best and simplest option would be to go with the 2.4GHz band. It has good penetration capabilities over long distances. It should be able to get atleast a good 18Mbps.

Comment: I'm currently using the 2.4GHz band and still getting 3-7 mbps

Comment: @JDas If Zachary blacklists the correct wireless driver for his device, won't the speed go down to zero???

Comment: I added it as a reference point. @chili555 . it was my mistake. i'll remove it right now.